# nodejs - Returning a Promise after the end of a for loop

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I need to call an `async` function in a `for` loop where every iteration 'builds' an object. At the end of the loop, this object should be resolved in a `Promise` so that the next function in chain can pick it up for further processing. While the iterations get the data correctly, I am not able to collect the 'built up' object and return it. I keep getting `{}`. Can you please help me resolve this?

```
async function imageDetailsCache(images) {
    var imageData = {}; // This object is built up every iteration
    var imageNo = '';
    var promises = [];
    //
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        imageNo = images[i]
        promises.push(
            new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                imageDetails(imageNo, 'BIG').then(function (result) {
                    imageData[imageNo] = { 'BIG': result }
                    imageDetails(imageNo, 'TINY').then(function (result) {
                        imageData[imageNo] = { 'TINY': result }
                    })
                })
                resolve(imageData)
            })
        )
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function (result) {
        return result; // Always {}
    })
}
```

Comment: `return result; // Always {}` - that's unlikely because the result of `Promise.all` is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! You were calling `resolve` before the asynchronous things in `imageDetails` had happened. And don't use `then` when working with `async`/`await`:

```
async function imageDetailsCache(images) {
    var imageData = {}; // This object is built up every iteration
    var promises = images.map(async (image) => {
        var result = await imageDetails(image, 'BIG');
        imageData[image] = { 'BIG': result }
        var result = await imageDetails(image, 'TINY');
        imageData[image] = { 'TINY': result };
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);
    return imageData;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the async function passed to map return a promise?

Comment: @danh It does, because it's an `async` function. The returned promise does fulfill when the body with all its `await`ed promises finishes.

Comment: @cogitoergosum Right, thanks, there isn't even any `result` in my code

Comment: I tried a variation of your example - https://pastebin.com/PVevygSm But, `data` keeps turning out to be empty.

Comment: So the function that calls `imageDetailsCache(images)` keeps getting a `Promise { <pending> }` not the `imageData` object.

Comment: @cogitoergosum In your pastebin, the `async function` that you pass as a callback to `map` doesn't `return` anything to resolve the promise with. Do not mix `then` with `await` syntax.

Comment: @cogitoergosum Yes, `imageDetailsCache` returns a promise for the `imageData`. You cannot get the asynchronous result immediately.

Comment: I was using `await` and `then` because `imageCacheData` returns a resolved Promise. I don't see a `return` in your example above ...

Comment: @cogitoergosum I don't `return` anything because I ignore the results of `Promise.all`, I only wait for it. In your pastebin code you are doing something with the `data` array and wonder why it is empty - it contains the results of the `promises` which all are `undefined`. And you should use *either* `await` *or* `then` to deal with promises, not both.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Promises, then: 
I guess this will work:

```
async function imageDetailsCache(images) {
var imageData = {};
var promises = [];
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { // notice the let instead of var
   promises.push(
         new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            imageDetails(images[i], 'BIG')
                .catch(e => {reject(e)})
                .then( rBig => {
                    imageDetails(images[i], 'SMALL')
                        .catch(e => { reject(e)})
                        .then( rSmall => {
                            imageData[images[i]] = {
                                 'BIG': rBig ,
                                 'SMALL': rSmall
                            }
                            resolve ({
                                BIG: rBig,
                                SMALL: rSmall
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            )
        );
}
await Promise.all(promises);
return imageData;
```

}

imageDetailsCache(images).then((r) => {console.log(r)});

I do have to emphasize that using async & await properly (as https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi suggested) it will make this code cleaner .

Personally I would do it like this:

```
async function imageDetailsCache(images) {
var imageData = {};
var promises = [];
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    try {
        imageData[images[i]] = {
            'BIG': await imageDetails(images[i], 'BIG') ,
            'SMALL': await imageDetails(images[i], 'SMALL')
        }
    } catch (e)  {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
return imageData;
```

}

imageDetailsCache(images).then((r) => {console.log(r)});

Hope it helps!

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: I was just trying to show cogitoergosum how to fix his code while pointing at the good practices you wrote earlier. I do agree with what you wrote, that is why I marked your answer as right.

Comment: So `var d = imageDetailsCache(images)` should make `d` have the complete `imageData`?

Comment: @ancag It's not just "cleaner". Using the `new Promise` constructor like you did will prevent errors from being handled. Just use `then` chaining instead.

Comment: @cogitoergosum I modified my answer with two example. Hope it helps.

Comment: @bergi you are right :) the function should be async, because it has to wait until all the promises are ready also in the previous comment I did not .catch on errors. Thanks for the heads up!